# How to use angularjs directive to append HTML content to thead in table?

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I want to append `<tr><button></button></tr>` to the `<thead>`in the below html.

```
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    Header 1
    </tr>
    </thead>

  </table>
```

Is it possible to achieve the idea above using angular directives?

Answer (score 1):

in your linking function of your costum directive you can use

```
angular.element(document).find("thead").append("<tr><button></button></tr>")
```

your directive could look like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myDirective', ['$document', function($document) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      angular.element(document).find("thead").append("<tr><button></button></tr>")
    }
  };
}]);
```

carefull i havent tested this code but this is the way to manipulate DOM in custom directives ,i will make a plunker when i can

Comment: you need to post your full code to help you further or even better make a plunker with it